# mysql #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

This is for my thesis and the dead end is later i don't know what i do wrong here .. Im hoping that someone can help me to know what's wrong here thanks

```
SELECT 
        flower_id,
        flower_name,
        flower_description,
        flower_price,
        flower_category,
        (quantity - (SELECT 
                SUM(q.quantity_value)
            FROM
                orders_details od
                    INNER JOIN
                cart_details cd ON cd.cart_id = od.cart_id
                    INNER JOIN
                quantities q ON q.quantity_id = cd.quantity_id
            WHERE
                od.flag = 1 AND cd.flower_id = flower_id
            GROUP BY cd.flower_id)) AS 'quantity',
        mfg_date,
        exp_date
    FROM
        flower_details,
        categories
    WHERE
        flower_details.flower_category = categories.category_id
```

What im doing here is getting the total quantity of products  from customer bought minus to inventory stocks

Comment: What do you want? What are you getting?

Comment: getting the difference total of products from product stocks - customer bought product and the some information of the product

Comment: Try to execute only subquery and debug it

Comment: i already do that it says #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Please help me . i dont know what's wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subselect return more then a rows  you should join the sum  using an inner join on subselect 
If your subselect return more then a rows  you should join the sum  using an inner join on subselect  inner join on subselect

```
      SELECT 
        flower_details.flower_id,
        flower_name,
        flower_description,
        flower_price,
        flower_category,
        flower_details.quantity - t1.quantity, 
        mfg_date,
        exp_date
    FROM flower_details 
    INNER JOIN categories ON flower_details.flower_category = categories.category_id
    INNER JOIN       (
                SELECT  cd.flower_id , 
                SUM(q.quantity_value) AS quantity
            FROM
                orders_details od
                    INNER JOIN
                cart_details cd ON cd.cart_id = od.cart_id
                    INNER JOIN
                quantities q ON q.quantity_id = cd.quantity_id
            WHERE
                od.flag = 1 AND cd.flower_id = flower_id
            GROUP BY cd.flower_id
    )  t1 on flower_details.flower_id = t1.flower_id
```

Comment: Column 'quantity' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Column 'quantity' in field list is ambiguous sir :(

Comment: where is the subtract operation sir

Comment: added subtract and quantity ambiguity  removed .. answer updated .

Comment: i made the od.flower_id  to flower_id sir

Comment: @CloudStrife   you know the data schema and the real relation between the tables .. i just look  at the "aspect" of the query

Comment: 5am  .. where do you live .. ?

Comment: Philippines sir i just need ready my explanatio for our defense later hehe thanks again